# Is Tick-Tock the Crocodile dead in Hook?

Tags: peter-pan

In the 1991 film *Hook*, Captain Hook implies that he killed Tick-Tock the Crocodile previously off-screen. Spoilers ahead.

> **HOOK**: Finally I'm going to kill Peter Pan...
> ...that cocky boy who cut off my hand and fed it to the crocodile!
> And who killed that cunning crocodile? 
> Who stuffed him?
> Who made him into a quiet clock?
>
> **CROWD**: Hook!
>
> <sub>source: [Hook transcript](https://peterpan.fandom.com/wiki/Hook_(1991_film)/Transcript#:%7E:text=Finally%20I%27m%20going,quiet%20clock%3F%20%2D%20Hook!)</sub>

Later Hook doubts his previous claim:

> **HOOK**: What is it? I hear it. I hear it again. Smee, it's that crocodile, back from the dead. Is that the clock?

Nevertheless Smee seems confident:

> **SMEE**: You killed that croc years ago.

However the above statements all seem to be at odds with what we actually see in the film's final confrontation (start at timestamp 1:27):

As you can see Tick-Tock appears to roar, move, and then swallow Hook before just as quickly reverting to a seemingly lifeless statue. What are we to make of this?

Was magic somehow involved? Was Hook exaggerating before? If so, surely the lack of food and water would do the trick, given the capture was "years ago" if Smee is to be believed.

Answer (score 11):

The answer appears to be '*don't think about it too much*'. Peter certainly doesn't and this is, after all is said and done, a world of magic and wonderment.

> But just as it seemed that all was lost, there was Tink,
> darting out of nowhere to deflect the blow just enough that
> it missed Peter and lodged instead in the belly of the
> crocodile. Gasses and dust spewed forth in a cloud, blinding
> Hook. He struggled to pull free and could not. The
> crocodile began to shake and shudder, and the clock
> tumbled out of its jaws, barely missing Hook as it struck the
> ground behind him with a thud. The tower began to rock,
> then to teeter. A moaning rose, as if a ghost had been
> awakened. The Lost Boys drew back. The pirates who still
> remained began to scatter, fleeing with wild cries. Peter
> pulled Jack and Maggie away.
>
> Hook flailed, making the crocodile clock rock dangerously. He screamed like a madman. Finally he wrenched free, but his efforts snapped the last of the crocodile’s fastenings and it began to fall toward him. Hook tried to run, but ended up stumbling over the fallen clock. He lay thrashing, horror mirrored in his red eyes. The crocodile was descending, its jaws cracked wide.
>
> Hook gasped. Down came the crocodile with a crash. And Captain James Hook disappeared down its throat with a gulp.
>
> After the dust had settled, they all walked forward to peer
> into the crocodile’s jaws. One after another they bent down
> for a look, amazement on their faces.
> Captain Hook was gone.
> **“Where’d he go?” Maggie wanted to know. But no one
> had an answer.**
> Then the cry of “victory banquet” went up again, and
> everyone began to parade about the fallen crocodile
> shouting and cheering, “No more Hook!” and “Hurray fo
> Pan the Man!”
>
> <sub><sup>[Hook: A Novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34920.Hook)</sup></sub>

Comment: The line "as if a ghost had been awakened" actually really helps in my opinion. Was it alive all along? No. But its ghost haunted the Clock/body, usually dormant but one day Hook drew too close and the ghost of Tick-Tock saw its chance to exact its revenge and ended Hook.